# code added to a xlsm worksheet while saving in VBA keeps diapearing

Tags: excel, vba

I build a xlsm file that takes a database of a few hundred lines as input, processes them and outputs a few seperate .xlsm files, each containing some rearanged part of the input.

I would like to add a simple "Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick" sub to each of the generated output files.

when working through the input, at the end of the for loop, I do the following:

```
Dim numLines As Integer

Set CodeCopy = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule

numLines = CodeCopy.CountOfLines

NewBook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule.AddFromString CodeCopy.Lines(1, numLines)

AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, _

FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
NewBook.Saved = False

NewBook.SaveAs Filename:="cw_" & cw & "_" & myVendors(N), _
ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, _
FileFormat:=52

NewBook.Close
```

If I add a break before the "NewBook.Close", everything seems to work. The split file is shown as a seperate project and "Sheet2" contains the required code.

If I let the sub resume, the file is closed but if I reopen it manually the code is gone.
If I instead stop at the "NewBook.Close" and save the split file seperately the code remains in the file.

Comment: Try  `NewBook.Close SaveChanges:=True`

Comment: Have you thought about putting a template sheet into the original Workbook that contains the code you want, and copy this sheet to the new Workbook before you start to fill it. This works for sure.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using and what OS?

Comment: Also, what do you think `Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges` is doing?  If the new workbook is new then it won't do anything.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestions so far.

@damian I just tried that but it does not change anything. Thanks anyway

Comment: @FunThomas that sounds like a very good Idea. for my code it would sadly mean that I have to redo a lot of code. I will try this workarround if I find no easy fix.

Comment: @Gareth I am using Windows 10 and Excel 2013 // conflict resolution is necessary because the produced outputs have to be overwritten when running the script one day later in some rare cases.

Comment: @Waldemar Kogtev. IIRC `xlLocalSessionChanges` only relates to shared workbooks.  It won't overwrite an existing file.  Check the date/time of the new file to ensure that it has saved as expected.

Comment: @gareth It seems I had misunderstood this one. on top of it I was using 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
while saving so taking out
xlLocalSessionChanges 
did not change anything. both before and afterwards it creates new files as well as overwrites old files - without the VBA code though...

Comment: @FunThomas I adapted the code to use your suggestion and it works perfectly. I don't really see it as the answer to why I have the problem in the first place but it is a good workarround. If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I would select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why your code is gone after save - however, I generally think writing code using the VBE is not a good idea. And you need to allow this in the Trust Center Settings where it is usually disabled (for good reasons).

It is much easier to put the code into a template worksheet that sits in your workbook where your code sits. When create the new workbook, you simply copy this template sheet into it and voilà, all the code is copied with it. You can also put some formatting into the template - no need to do the formatting via code.

If you want, you can completely hide the template sheet - you just have to temporarily set it to visible before you copy it (use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to prevent flicker).

If you use the `Copy`-method of a worksheet without parameters, Excel will create a new Workbook with only this sheet. Of course, you can also create the new Workbook and use the `Copy`-method with `Before` or `After`-parameter.

```
Const TemplateSheetName = "Template"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TemplateSheetName)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim saveVisibility As Long
    saveVisibility = .Visible§
    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    .Copy
    .Visible = saveVisibility
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Dim newWb As Workbook, newWS As Worksheet

Set newWb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
Set newWS = newWb.Sheets(TemplateSheetName)
newWS.Name = "MyNewDataSheet"  ' You should assign a new name to the sheet
```